# UIView subclass access ViewController methods swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

In a couple of my projects I think I'm not created a great structure in many cases.

It could be a game where I've created a game board (think about chess) with a grid of 8 * 8 cells. Each cell has a gesture recognizer that relies on a subclass (cell.swift), with the game logic in a parent ViewController.

For arguments sake, let us say we want to display to the user which square they have touched.

I've found out how to do this from the subclassed UIView (obvs. create the alert in the subclassed UIView / cell.swift in this example)

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but it seems to break the structure of the app - but wouldn't it be the same accessing an action in the parent ViewController? What is the best way of approaching this>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rootViewController is the VC on the bottom of your stack. It's not a safe way to access the visible VC, and is rarely useful, in general (there are cases, but I doubt your app would find them useful).

What you likely want to use is a delegate pattern. Let's say the parent VC that displays your chess board (let's call this MyBoardViewController), conforms to a protocol like the following. MyView is whatever custom UIView class you're using for the chess squares:

```
protocol SquareAlertHandler {
    func handleSquarePressed(sender : myView)
}
```

And add the following property to your MyView class:

```
weak var delegate : SquareAlertHandler?
```

And replace whatever event handler you're currently using, with the following (I'm assuming you're using a UIButton in IB to handle the press, and have arbitrarily named the outlet 'didPress:'):

```
@IBAction didPress(sender : UIButton) {
    delegate?.handleSquarePressed(self)
}
```

Now, add the protocol to your MyBoardViewController, and define the method:

```
class MyBoardViewController : UIViewController, SquareAlertHandler {

    ... ... ...
    func handleSquarePressed(sender : myView) {
        // Do something to handle the press, here, like alert the user
    }
    ... ... ...
}
```

And finally, wherever you create the MyView instances, assign the MyBoardViewController instance as the delegate, and you're good to go.

Depending on your Swift literacy, this may be confusing. Adding code, so that I can at least match up the class names, would help to clarify things.

Comment: This is fine, I understand protocols and delegates and I think leaving this as a general answer might be useful to other readers. Thank you - just learning and it is actually hard to find any resource that covers this type of (not quite trivial) issue.

Comment: Sounds good! Coding patterns are tough when you change languages frequently, or are new to a language. Good luck, and all that.

Comment: One issue - I've used delegates before and always have set the delegate. Here it seems to always be nil - what is going on?

Comment: The line weak var delegate : SquareAlertHandler? declares a delegate as an Optional, but does not assign it. Declaring properties as Optionals is a good (but not universal) rule of thumb in Swift, for reasons I won't go into. In order to access the delegate, you must first explicitly set it. Something like : myViewInstance.delegate = self, if you're creating those views in the parent VC.

Comment: Yes, I got this. Continuing the chess idea, I would create a new cell for each. So each cell needs to be instantiated with myViewInstance.delegate = self

Comment: That is correct. Classes are pass by reference, and all that, so even if you have the full 64 squares, it's not terribly memory intensive.